# Messagebox response gives unhandled exception

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a tool for disabling users. And I want to create a "please confirm you want to do this" message box.

So i made the following function to disable the user, but when i call the function and press No on the messagebox I get an unhandled exception.

If i run the first IF statement with some code afterward it work fine, just not when I call the function.

Any ideas?

```
function DisableUser { 
    if ([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Are you really really really sure you want to disable this user?`n`n" + $labelNameValue.Text, "Are you sure sure?", "YesNo", "Warning") -eq "No") {
        Break
    }

    $DisabledUsersOU = "OU=Disabled Users,DC=domain,DC=local"

    $userObject = Get-ADUser -Identity $textboxSearch.Text -Properties Manager
    $adGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $userObject.SamAccountName | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne "Domain Users" } | Sort-Object

    # REMOVE -WhatIf

    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $labelUsernameValue.Text -MemberOf $adGroups -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
    $userObject | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $DisabledUsersOU -WhatIf
    Set-ADUser $userObject -Manager $Null -Description "$date Disabled by $env:USERNAME" -WhatIf
    Disable-ADAccount -Identity $userObject -WhatIf

    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("User would have been disabled if this button worked!`nBut is doesn't, so nothing happend.", "BANG!!!!!!", "Ok", "Information")
}
```

This is the error message i get:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Management.Automation.BreakException: System error.
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ThrowInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
   at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.<InvokeWithPipe>b__0()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Boolean propagateAllExceptionsToTop, List`1 variablesToDefine, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, Object[] args)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeAsDelegateHelper(Object dollarUnder, Object dollarThis, Object[] args)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Is it erroring out at the if statement? If so, change `$labelNameValue.Text` to `$($labelNameValue.Text)` and try.

Comment: No. I trying running debug and IF statement runs fine and evaluates as "No". It seems to be failing when it runs Break.

Comment: Okay, I am unable to reproduce the error you run into. Perhaps you can write a code that doesn't use `break`. For instance, you can change the code for `if statement` to check for `Yes` instead and put the user disable code inside the `if statement block`. I also strongly believe that would be the safer approach too in your case. To rely on `Yes` instead of `No` and `Break`.

Comment: You have a fair point. I changed it around and that works perfectly :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get this error. Maybe because the way you show your messagebox can make it appear **behind** other windows. Running it several times without realizing earlier instances were waiting for a user input, might result in error messages.

Perhaps better try this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic

$title   = "Are you sure sure?"
$message = "Are you really really really sure you want to disable this user?`r`n`r`n$($labelNameValue.Text)"
$buttons = "YesNo"     # choose from "OKOnly", "OKCancel", "AbortRetryIgnore", "YesNoCancel", "YesNo", "RetryCancel"
$icon    = "Question"  # choose from "Critical", "Question", "Exclamation", "Information"
if ([Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox($message, "$buttons,SystemModal,$icon", $title) -eq 'No') {
    return   # exit the function
}
```

instead of

```
if ([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Are you really really really sure you want to disable this user?`n`n" + $labelNameValue.Text, "Are you sure sure?", "YesNo", "Warning") -eq "No") {
    Break
}
```

I'm a bit confused with all the different ways you address the user to delete.. I can see `$textboxSearch.Text`, `$labelUsernameValue.Text`, `$labelNameValue.Text` and `$userObject` all mixed in that function. Maybe think this over a bit longer?

Because of the `SystemModal` flag, the messagebox will appear on top, so there is no chance of hidden alertboxes anymore.

<sup>P.S. `break` does not exit a function. It is generally used in loops and switch statements. If used in this context, break will "break" out of a loop or a switch statement. Use `return` instead</sup>

Hope that helps

Comment: I just tested. Keept everything as shown in the example. Just changes  `Break` to `return`. And that worked. Thank you. I agree, the code need some cleaning up, no doubt about that.